# cakephp save is not working 2.X

Tags: sql, cakephp-2.3, last-insert-id

I am using **CakePHP 2.3**, I want to save data as follows follows:

```
$insertUser  = array(
    'Name' => $Name,
    'LastName' => $lastName,
    'password' => $password,
    'email' => $email,
    'TimeStamp' => $presentTime,
    'RefererUserId' => $refererId // set the referer user id
);

$this->SystemUser->saveAll($insertUser) // save record in table.
```

The above code is not working. I tried another method like:

```
  $this->SystemUser->query("INSERT INTO system_users(Name,LastName,password,email,TimeStamp,RefererUserId) VALUES ('{$Name}','{$lastName}','{$password}','{$email}','{$presentTime}','{$refererId}')");
```

How can I now get the last inserted id? I used `getLastInsertId()` to get last inserted id, as below:

```
$lastid = $this->SystemUser->getLastInsertId();
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$insertUser` should be the following

```
$insertUser['SystemUser']  = array(
  'Name' => $Name,
  'LastName' => $lastName,
  'password' => $password,
  'email' => $email,
  'TimeStamp' => $presentTime,
  'RefererUserId' => $refererId // set the referer user id
);
```

Then you should be save data as like

```
if($this->SystemUser->save($insertUser)) {
    $lastid = $this->SystemUser->getLastInsertId();
} else {
   debug($this->SystemUser->validationErrors); die();
}
```

> This will probably give you the info you need (assuming it's not saving because of invalid data, of course):

```
debug($this->SystemUser->validationErrors); die();
```

That's it.

Comment: I have my answer. check it.

Comment: the problem is in validation :-
   var $validate = array(

 'password' => array(
  'ruleName' => array(
   //'rule' => '(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)',
   'rule' => '((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$)',
   'message' => "Password should contain: 8 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number"
  )
 ),
    'confirm_password' => array(
  'ruleName2' => array(
   'rule' => array('matchPasswords','password'),   'message' => "Password and confirm password must be same."
)
    ));
I am not getting the issue.. if possible can you please help me out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14505630/2460470 or http://caky.de/en/models/data-validation/custom-validation-rules.html#custom-regular-expression-validation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. **SystemUser** is assumed as your model name.

```
$this->user_data = array(
        'SystemUser' => array(
                  'Name' => $Name,
                  'LastName' => $lastName,
                  'password' => $password,
                  'email' => $email,
                  'TimeStamp' => $presentTime,
                  'RefererUserId' => $refererId // set the referer user id
        ));

    if ($this->SystemUser->save($this->user_data)) {
       $lastid = $this->SystemUser->getLastInsertId();
    } else {
       // do something
    }
```

Comment: i have found the issue.. but i am not aware of its soln.
if I save $this->data directly than my save command is working.

 if ($this->SystemUser->save($this->data)) {
       $lastid = $this->SystemUser->getLastInsertId();
    } else {
       // do something
    }

but i need i have to add the md5( password ) and some more fields?
how can I achieve that ?

Comment: the problem is in validation :- var $validate = array( 'password' => array( 'ruleName' => array( //'rule' => '(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)', 'rule' => '((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$)', 'message' => "Password should contain: 8 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 number" ) ), 'confirm_password' => array( 'ruleName2' => array( 'rule' => array('matchPasswords','password'), 'message' => "Password and confirm password must be same." ) )); I am not getting the issue.. if possible can you please help me out.

Comment: function matchPasswords($field = array(),$compare_field = null) {
        foreach($field as $key => $value){
   $v1 = trim($value);
   $v2 = trim($this->data[$this->name][$compare_field]);
   if($v1 != "" && $v2 !="" && $v1 != $v2){
    return false; 
   }
   return true;
  }
   }